# Pytest how to mock threading.Timer

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I understand how to mock the current time, which I have tried.The problem is my program uses a `threading.Timer`, which seems unaffected by mocking the time.

Surely this problem happened before. How can I "sleep" my unit test or somehow mock the passage of time?

Calling `sleep` is probably a bad idea because the actual speed of execution is depended on what hardware the unit test is running on.

Any advise on this issue?

Comment: What do you mean you know how to mock the current time?  Can you show the relevant parts of your code?  And, can you also show how your program uses threading.Timer?   And, finally, can you explain what you try to achieve with your tests?

Comment: The program uses Timer to execute some task 60 seconds from now. I need to test that the task was indeed executed after 60 seconds. I want to achieve this by measuring the task output, as opposed to counting how many times the callback function was executed. The timer is embedded within a larger piece of code. (Otherwise it would appear I'm trying to test the timer class itself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Upate:** Your comment finally clarifies what you intend to achieve, namely not having to wait for real 60s in your test.  There are already some discussions of the topic how to unit-test code that works with timers:

- [How do you unit test classes that use timers internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879971/how-do-you-unit-test-classes-that-use-timers-internally)
- [Unit testing a class that uses a Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495830/unit-testing-a-class-that-uses-a-timer)

The basic idea is, to use a technique called "inversion of control": Instead of allowing the system under test (SUT) to control the time, change the design such that the test can do this.  There are many different ways, for example a) turn the timer object into an argument, or, b) access it within the SUT in a helper method that can be overridden by the test, or, have the SUT obtain it from a factory (which you replace during testing), or, make it possible for a test to overwrite it with a setter method etc.

**Original Answer (focused on a different aspect):**

From your question and comment I conclude that for your tests you accept that the execution of the test will actually take about 60s (quoting you: "I need to test that the task was indeed executed after 60 seconds." and "How can I "sleep" my unit test [...]").  You want to test that the program uses the timer to execute the task - which is rather an integration test scenario than a unit-test scenario.

The test description is still not very precise, so I will make some assumptions.  Let's assume that you want to test that the "task" is not executed before, say, 59s, but also not later than, say, 61s.  There are several ways to achieve this.  One simple approach is, to actually use sleep for 58s, check that the task was not executed yet (test case 1), and have another test case with a sleep of 61s and check that the task was executed.  But, due various effects it is not fully robust, as you already mentioned.  You can make it more robust by enlarging the time interval.

Another approach requires a design change: Within your program you read the clock time immediately before starting the timer and pass this time stamp to your scheduled task.  Within the scheduled task the first thing is again to read the clock.  This time can then be compared against the other time stamp.  These results are made accessible for the test, which reads out the time stamps or the delta.  This is likely more accurate, but still is, for example, influenced by scheduling effects caused by the operating system.

I would say, since this question is about python programs, you will just have to live with a certain degree of inaccuracy.  Even in real time systems with programs in C or even in assembly language, reaching a high level of accuracy is challenging - but we are talking about different levels of accuracy here (microseconds and better).

Comment: The issue is not with time measurement accuracy. The problem is that I do not want my test suite to wait 59 or 61 seconds each time it is executed.

Comment: Thank you, the reason I didn't find those is because I was looking for python specific answers. Thanks for linking those questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [the source for `threading.Timer`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f75d59e1a896115bd52f543a417c665d6edc331f/Lib/threading.py#L1142-L1167), you can see the delay effect comes from the `Timer` (which is a `Thread` in itself) just calling `.wait()` on a `threading.Event` object.

You could use `unittest.mock` or `pytest-mock` to replace the `Event.wait()` implementation with one that doesn't actually wait for anything.

Comment: while it may work for a while, mocking (or patching) internals of a 3rd party library produces very fragile tests. as soon as Thread stops using Event internally, your tests will break and you will have no idea why. i'd be very cautions about that approach.

Comment: @ierdna `threading` is not a 3rd party library. It's part of the standard library. The last time the Timer class was touched [was 8 years ago](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/f75d59e1a896115bd52f543a417c665d6edc331f/Lib/threading.py#L1142-L1167) (for a docstring change; the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/44f8696171f8d9e29c82e250ed90351dfb207da2) has been unchanged for 20 years), so I wouldn't expect it to change implementations very soon.

Comment: point taken, in this particular case it's probably fine; i guess in general, i would caution against patching internals of a component whose source you do not own.