# How to unit test a timer class (adapter pattern)?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, real-time

I'm currently abstracting the concept of timers so that my classes that need one can use mock timers in tests or different implementations in operative mode (e.g. threadpool timers, thread-affine timers, etc.). Therefore, I created this interface:

```
public interface ITimer : IDisposable
{
    bool IsEnabled { get; }
    bool IsAutoResetting { get; set; }
    TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }

    void Start();
    void Stop();

    event EventHandler IntervalElapsed;
}
```

Now I want to create a wrapper that adapts the `System.Threading.Timer` class and implements that interface. I want to do it using test-driven development. My class currently looks somewhat like this:

```
public sealed class ThreadPoolTimer : ITimer
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public bool IsEnabled { get; private set; }

    public bool IsAutoResetting { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }

    public ThreadPoolTimer()
    {
        Interval = this.GetDefaultInterval();
        _timer = new Timer(OnTimerCallback);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    public void Start()
    {

    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }

    private void OnTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        OnIntervalElapsed();
    }

    public event EventHandler IntervalElapsed;

    private void OnIntervalElapsed()
    {
        var handler = IntervalElapsed;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**My actual question is:** how would you write unit tests that describe the (soft real-time) requirements for the behavior of `Start`, `Stop` and `IntervalElapsed`?

In my opinion, i should use e.g. an `AutoResetEvent` and check if the event is raised within a certain timespan (maybe +/- 3ms). But writing that code somewhat violates the DAMP (descriptive and meaningful phrases) principle, I think. Is there an easier way to do this?

Should I make the dependency to `System.Threading.Timer` external and then maybe use a shim for testing purposes? Unfortunately, the .NET timers do not have a common interface (which would make my work obsolete...)

What are your thoughts on that topic? Is there any documentation that I have not found yet and that I should read?

Sorry for having actually more than one question in this post, but this testing of soft real-time requirements is quite interesting, I think.

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088313/unit-testing-system-timers-timer

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate because all these questions refer to classes that encapsulate a timer and how to mock it but none that implement the actual interface using TDD. Other questions on this are e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879971/how-do-you-unit-test-classes-that-use-timers-internally or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045/unit-testing-a-timer-based-application

Comment: creating a wrapper feels like a smell. I think the timer class in the framework is guaranteed to work. I'd subclass to test the subject to invoke my timer handlers or inject my own intervals to write a few integration tests.

Comment: @bryanbcook and how do you abstract from it? As I mentioned before, none of the timers in .NET implement a common interface. Not creating an adaptor (which this wrapper actually is) means that you cannot abstract from it in unit tests for classes that need a timer.

Comment: My point is that unless there is a really strong and compelling reason for the abstraction, it may not be needed. For example, a UI dispatcher won't pump background tasks if there is no UI, which can be a problem for tests. Timers on the other hand are fairly guaranteed so unless you are dynamically manipulating the timer or need to swap it out with different timing strategies, I would question why I need the abstraction.

Comment: @bryanbcook If you're doing Test-Driven Development, you have to abstracts from it if your unit-testing a class that has a dependency on a timer, otherwise it would not be a unit test, but an integration test. Also, by mocking a timer you can easily create the scenarios where your system under test has to behave in a certain way. Imagine a class that processes data and if this data processing takes more than 50ms, then an additional processing step should happen. How would you easily test this with a real timer on any given machine? Mocks are necessary to create a closed test environment.

Comment: I'm well aware of all of this. My position is that of pragmatism - depending on the behavior being tested a simple integration test may be sufficient. I'd argue that if you mock out the timer you will have to write integration tests anyway. If this abstraction is used everywhere you have a compelling reason; if it's used in one spot you might not. Mocks are not a requirement for TDD as I've been doing it before mocking frameworks were invented.

Comment: Well, let's say we agree to disagree on that :-) In my opinion, a unit test should only test one class with all dependencies being mocked. But maybe we have a different approach on Test-Driven Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one answered this question yet, I'll tell you how I approached the problem: I used the spy pattern to actually implement the code that observes the behavior of the timer. The class looks like this:

```
public class ThreadPoolTimerSpy : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ThreadPoolTimer _threadPoolTimer;

    private int _intervalElapsedCallCount;

    private readonly ManualResetEvent _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public int NumberOfIntervals { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }

    public ThreadPoolTimerSpy(ThreadPoolTimer threadPoolTimer)
    {
        if (threadPoolTimer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("threadPoolTimer");
        _threadPoolTimer = threadPoolTimer;
        _threadPoolTimer.IntervalElapsed += OnIntervalElapsed;
        NumberOfIntervals = 1;
    }

    public void Measure()
    {
        _intervalElapsedCallCount = 0;
        _resetEvent.Reset();
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        _threadPoolTimer.Start();

        _resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    private void OnIntervalElapsed(object sender, EventArgs arguments)
    {
        _intervalElapsedCallCount++;

        if (_intervalElapsedCallCount < NumberOfIntervals)
            return;

        _threadPoolTimer.Stop();
        EndTime = DateTime.Now;
        _resetEvent.Set();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _threadPoolTimer.Dispose();
        _resetEvent.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This class takes a `ThreadPoolTimer` and registers to its `IntervalElapsed` event. One can specify how much intervals the spy should wait until it stops measuring. As I'm using a `ManualResetEvent` to block the thread that starts the timer in the `Measure` method, all calls to that  method are synchronous, which results in DAMP code in the actual test class, in my opinion.

A test method that uses the spy would look like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void InitializeTestEnvironment()
{
    _testTarget = new ThreadPoolTimerBuilder().WithAutoResetOption(true)
                                              .WithInterval(100)
                                              .Build() as ThreadPoolTimer;
    Assert.IsNotNull(_testTarget);
    _spy = new ThreadPoolTimerSpy(_testTarget);
}

[TestMethod]
public void IntervalElapsedMustBeRaisedExactlyTenTimesAfter1000Milliseconds()
{
    CheckIntervalElapsed(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
}

private void CheckIntervalElapsed(int numberOfIntervals, TimeSpan expectedTime, TimeSpan toleranceInterval)
{
    _spy.NumberOfIntervals = numberOfIntervals;
    _spy.Measure();
    var passedTime = _spy.EndTime - _spy.StartTime;
    var timingDifference = Math.Abs(expectedTime.Milliseconds - passedTime.Milliseconds);
    Assert.IsTrue(timingDifference <= toleranceInterval.Milliseconds, string.Format("Timing difference: {0}", timingDifference));
}
```

If you have any questions or recommendations, please feel free to leave a comment.

Besides: the tolerance interval I have to choose to make the tests pass are relatively high. I thought that maybe 3 to 5 milliseconds might suffice, but in the end for ten intervals I figured out that the actual measured time span is up to 72ms different than the expected time of 1000ms in this case. Well, never use a managed runtime for real time applications, I guess...